# convert a 1bit bitmap to 8 bit bitmap xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bitmap, android-bitmap

I am working with xamarin android and I was given a 1bit bitmap and I need to convert it to an 8 bit bitmap.  I've seen some examples of going from 8 bit to 1 bit and 8 bit to 16 or 24 bit.

I don't have the lockbits method so I need to figure something else out I think I can use copy methods with byte buffers but unsure what I need to do to accomplish it.

anyone ever tried something like this that could help me out?

Comment: You mean a on-off pixel style encoding? You won't be able to pull additional information from it to 8-bit, if that's what you're aiming to do.

Comment: there are lots of examples on SO of doing bitmap --> monochrome conversion in Android.  You can probably use them as a guide for doing the reverse process.  You'll have to convert to C# but they will show you which native API's are being used

Answer (score 0):

I found this on an [external website](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d4df65c9-d177-405a-b274-87aadcc063e7/convert-1-bit-bitmap-to-8-bit-bitmap?forum=netfxbcl):

```
  BitmapImage Bmp1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Temp\\Creek1bpp.bmp"));
  FormatConvertedBitmap Bmp8 = new FormatConvertedBitmap(Bmp1, PixelFormats.Gray8, BitmapPalettes.BlackAndWhite, 1);
  BitmapFrame Bmp8Frame = BitmapFrame.Create(Bmp8);
  BmpBitmapEncoder Enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
  Enc.Frames.Add(Bmp8Frame);
  Enc.Save(new FileStream("C:\\Temp\\Creek8bpp.bmp", FileMode.Create));
```

Comment: FormatConvertedBitmap doesn't exist in the xamarin framework (already tried it) but thanks for trying!